# Eclipse plugin - getting the IStackframe object from a selection in DebugView

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

So, this is the problem I am stuck at for a few weeks.
I am developing an Eclipse plugin which fills in a View with custom values depending on a particular StackFrame selection in the Debug View.
In particular, I want to listen to the stackframe selected and would like to get the underlying `IStackFrame` object.

However, I have tried more than a dozen things and all of them have failed. So I tried adding `DebugContextListener` to get the `DebugContextEvent` and finally the selection. However, the main issue is that `ISelection` doesn't return the underlying `IStackFrame` object. It instead returns an object of type `AbstractDMVMNode.DMVMContext`. I tried getting an adapter but that didn't work out too. I posted this question sometime back also:

[Eclipse Plugin Dev- Extracting IStackFrame object from selection in Debug View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615273/eclipse-plugin-dev-extracting-istackframe-object-from-selection-in-debug-view)

Since then, I have tried out many different approaches. I tried adding `IDebugEventSetListener` (but this failed as it cannot identify stack frame selection in the debug view).
I tried adding an object contribution action but this too was pointless as it ultimately returned me an `ISelection` which is useless as it only returns me an object of class `AbstractDMVMNode.DMVMContext` and not `IStackframe`.

Moreover, I checked out the implementation of the `VariablesView` source code itself in the org.eclipse.debug.ui plugin. It looks like a few versions back (VariablesView source code in version 3.2), the underlying logic was to use the `ISelection` and get the `IStackFrame`. All the other resources on the internet also advocate the same. However, now, this scheme no longer works as `ISelection` doesn't return you an `IStackFrame`. Also, the source code for the latest eclipse Debug plugin (which doesn't use this scheme) was not very intuitive for me.

Can anyone tell how I should proceed ? Is hacking the latest Eclipse source code for VariablesView my only option ? This doesn't look like a good design practice and I believe there should be a much more elegant way of doing this.

PS: I have tried all the techniques and all of them return an `ISelection`. So, if your approach too return the same thing, then it is most likely incorrect.

Edit (Code snippet for trying to adapt the `ISelection`):

```
// Following is the listener implemnetation
IDebugContextListener flistener = new IDebugContextListener() {
    @Override
    public void debugContextChanged(DebugContextEvent event) {
            if ((event.getFlags() & DebugContextEvent.ACTIVATED) > 0) {
                contextActivated(event.getContext());
            }
    };
};

// Few things I tried in the contextActivated Method
    //Attempt 1 (Getting the Adapter):
    private void contextActivated(ISelection context) {
        if (context instanceof StructuredSelection) {
            Object data = ((StructuredSelection) context).getFirstElement();
            if( data instanceof IAdaptable){
                System.out.println("check1");
                IStackFrame model = (IStackFrame)((IAdaptable)data).getAdapter(IStackFrame.class);
                if(model != null){
                    System.out.println("success" + model.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Attemp2 (Directly getting it from ISelection):
    private void contextActivated(ISelection context) {
        if (context instanceof StructuredSelection) {
            System.out.println("a");
            Object data = ((StructuredSelection) context).getFirstElement();
            if (data instanceof IStackFrame) {
                 System.out.println("yes");
            } else {
                 System.out.println("no" + data.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
        // This always execute the else and it prints: org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui.viewmodel.datamodel.AbstractDMVMNode.DMVMContext
    }

    // Attemp3 (Trying to obtain it from the viewer (similiar to object action binding in some ways):
    private void contextActivated(ISelection context) {
        VariablesView variablesView = (VariablesView) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(IDebugUIConstants.ID_VARIABLE_VIEW);
        if (variablesView != null) {    
            Object input = ((TreeViewer) variablesView.getViewer()).getInput();
            if(input != null) System.out.println(input.getClass().getName());

            if (input instanceof IStackFrame) {
                System.out.println("success");

            } else if (input instanceof IThread) {
                System.out.println("success");
                try {
                    IStackFrame[] stackFrames = ((IThread) input).getStackFrames();
                    for (IStackFrame iStackFrame : stackFrames) {
                        printVariables(iStackFrame);
                    }
                } catch (DebugException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

While I am building this view to work with both JDT & CDT, I am testing it out on the C project. So, this might be the reason why I always get the returned object type as `AbstractDMVMNode.DMVMContext`.  Should my implementation be different to handle both these cases ? I believe I should be building a generic view. Also, if `AbstractDMVMNode.DMVMContext` is CDT specific, I should I go about implementing it for the CDT case?

Comment: I have inferred from your question that this is for CDT using DSF. If your reference to Version 3.2 is about Eclipse version, then you are comparing apples and oranges a little. Eclipse 3.2 would have been using a CDT with CDI debug interface (which as of next Eclipse release no longer exists). Have you reviewed http://help.eclipse.org/mars/nftopic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/dsf/intro/dsf_programming_intro.html?cp=13_0_5 ?

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with CDT. The DebugView is shared across both the CDT & JDT so its underlying functionality I guess shouldn't be tied up with CDT. Also, I looked at the org.eclipse.debug.ui plugin which is not a part of CDT.

Comment: AbstractDMVMNode.DMVMContext is a CDT DSF specific type. If you share your code attempt at adapting that would be great to see. The JDT puts objects of type IStackFrame in the DebugView, CDT DSF does not.

Comment: Added the source code for my attempts at adapting the ISelection. Also, now I realize that while I do want to build a genric view (which can work with both JDT & CDT), I tested only on c projects. Any pointers on how to make it work with CDT ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how DSF works. If you look at DSF you will find that nothing in DSF extends IStackFrame, so you can't adapt a DSF stack frame to IStackFrame like you can a JDT stack frame or a (deprecated) CDI stack frame. If you want to get information about a stack frame in DSF you need to use the IStack service (provided by DSF).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/jonahkichwacoders/cdt-examples/blob/cdt_8_6/com.kichwacoders.cdt.dsf.tutorial/src/com/kichwacoders/cdt/dsf/gdb/tutorial/framespy/polling/solution/FrameSpyPollingView.java) for an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Jonah. I will refer this example.